# Web Service Method Name is not valid (upload file via ajax w/ html5 formdata to aspx webservice)

Tags: c#, ajax, html, web-services

I am attempting to upload a file to a aspx webservice utilizing formdata and html5. If I don't set content type in the ajax call, it can't see the webservice. If I set it to json, it passes in null data.

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    file = $("#fileToUpload")[0].files[0];
    formData.append("file", file);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:50101/xxxxx.asmx/UploadFile',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(msg) {    
            console.log("error | " + JSON.stringify(msg));
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            console.log("Success | " + JSON.stringify(msg));    
        },
        data: formData,
        //data: {' + JSON.stringify(formdata)+'},
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});


<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="fileToUpload" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>



//....webservice....
    public String UploadFile(Object fileStreams)
        {
...
}
```

Comment: You want to send a file as json???

Comment: Not really, this is what a few examples I saw said to do....didn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Json Type

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",  // or GET
        url: "http://localhost:50101/xxxxx.asmx/UploadFile",
        data: formdata,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
        success: function(msg) {    
        console.log("error | " + JSON.stringify(msg));
        },
        error: function(msg) {
        console.log("Success | " + JSON.stringify(msg)); 
        }
    });
```

and check if you added `[webmethod]` attribute and no static modifier in the method declaration.